# "Access denied" on Remote winrm

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-remoting, winrm

I created a Windows VM on Windows Azure with winrm over SSL set.

But, I can't connect it using a powershell script.

When I'm running the following:

```
​Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://myniceapp.cloudapp.net:5986 
                -Credential "hostname/username"  
                -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck)
```

I'm getting a prompt asking for password and after I type it I manage to connect.

But, when I try to automate it, it always returns with "Access is denied"

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force "password"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "hostname/username", $securePassword 
​Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://myniceapp.cloudapp.net:5986 -Credential $mycreds -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck)
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

The full error looks like this:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server myniceaspp.cloudapp.net failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri https://myniceaspp.cloudapp ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (https:// myniceaspp...udapp.net:5986/:Uri) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

Comment: could be the case where the user you use is a machine admin but not a domain admin.

Comment: @Aravind doesn't that mean I shouldn't be able to connect using the prompt either?

Comment: hmm. That was the scenario I had this issue. depends on whether this VM is part of a domain(AD). If it is just one VM the above case is not applicable. I had got this working http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/introduction-remote-powershell-with-windows-azure/

Comment: For one, you switch between using `$cred` and `$mycreds` -- that won't work. -- But also your syntax is wrong --  it should be this: `$securePassword = ("securePassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force);` and then the next line to `$mycreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "userName", $securePassword;`

Answer (score 20):

Had similar problems recently. Would suggest you carefully check if the user you're connecting with has proper authorizations on the remote machine.

You can review permissions using the following command.

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Name Microsoft.PowerShell
```

Found this tip here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/17/configure-remote-security-settings-for-windows-powershell.aspx

It fixed it for me.

Comment: This is the identical issue we had when using an explicit AD group (*e.g. "mydomain\Server Admins"*) for server Administrator permissions.The only workaround is to explicitly add the user to the `Microsoft.Powershell` PS session configuration.The other workaround is to make the user an explicit local admin. **PSSession** doesn't seem to traverse user groups all the way down when group inheritance is being used..