# Certification Test Tool 1.2 for Azure Certified "Access is Denied"

Tags: windows, azure, powershell-remoting, winrm

My Azure marketplace VM image was removed suddenly by Microsoft due to WannaCry vulnerability.

I'm trying to run Certification Test Tool 1.2 for Azure Certified on a new VM created from the new patched image.

I am logged in as a local administrator and running the tool on the VM as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-vm-image-creation): "The certification tool runs on a running VM, provisioned from your user VM image, to ensure that the VM image is compatible with Microsoft Azure."

I've tried running the tool on default Classic (not Azure Resource Manager) Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter and Windows Server 2016 Datacenter VMs.

I've tried turning the Windows firewall and UAC off.

I have not tried [changing the firewall rules on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints) for the VM because: "When you create a Windows virtual machine in the Azure classic portal, common endpoints like those for Remote Desktop and Windows PowerShell Remoting are typically created for you automatically."

Here is the log created from running the tool on a brand new Azure Classic VM (with WannaCry patches applied):

```
5/18/2017 6:23:22 AM

Log generated by Certification Test Tool for Azure Certified

Test name: ****** Test Date :5/18/2017 6:23:22 AM Tested on: ******.cloudapp.net Test for: Microsoft Azure Test in: Windows Server
5/18/2017 6:23:24 AM

Test case/Verification: TestConnection
Description: Instantiates connection to the specified VM.

Connection Attempt: 1 Connecting to the Azure VM.... ******.cloudapp.net Error in connecting to the VM. Reason for not connecting to the VM : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server ******.cloudapp.net failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke() at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RunspacePoolInternal.EndOpen(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RemoteRunspacePoolInternal.Open() at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace.Open() at WindowsAddin.PSConnection.OpenSession() ----------------------------------------------------------------->
```

EDIT: Add a couple links.

Comment: Do you run the tool as the administrator?

Comment: You could check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680211/access-denied-on-remote-winrm).

Comment: Yes I'm running the tool as an administrator. I'm also logged in as a local administrator. I've even tried adding my user explicitly to the permissions for powershell as per the one answer for that question. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061088/unable-to-connect-to-vm-with-azure-certified-test-tool-1-2?rq=1) is also similar. But the accepted answer only applies to Azure Resource Manager VMs and the other answer suggests allowing the tool through the firewall, but I have my firewall turned off completely.

Comment: Since I posted this question I have tested with Windows Server 2008 R2 and I still get "Access Denied".

Comment: Could your RDP to your VM?

Comment: I have all three VMs up and running and I'm logged into them (using RDP) now. I would give you credentials so you can log in yourself. But you don't provide any contact details in your profile...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144542/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-salamiarmy).

Comment: FYI: Walter was not able to replicate the "Access is Denied". He literally joined exactly the same remote desktop session as I was using and it works for him but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to connect and run the tool, the trick was not to run it on the machine. You must run it from a remote machine. The tool denies access to itself.